# Exception in thread "http-bio-8078-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: postgresql

I have a web application build on Grails framework.
Earlier I was using oracle but now I switched to Postgres; and after I have moved to postgres I am facing this memory issues

Following is the stracktrace:-

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8078-AsyncTimeout" 
Error |
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Error |
2017-08-09 10:44:23,424 [http-bio-8078-exec-8] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
Error |
2017-08-09 10:44:23,452 [http-bio-8078-exec-8] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
Error |
2017-08-09 10:44:23,452 [http-bio-8078-exec-8] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
Error |
2017-08-09 10:44:23,452 [http-bio-8078-exec-8] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: It looks like an endless recursion.

Comment: Yes it is  showing it multiple time and in the end it closes the connection.

Comment: I think the error messages come from a logging statement inside of a catch block. If you have access to `spi.SqlExceptionHelper` you should place a breakpoint there.

Comment: No there is nothing like that.

Comment: Since it's an exception helper, it could be called from a catch block. Can you debug through this class?

Comment: Actually, this is a compiled class so it is hard to find that from where this class's methods are being called. This class has methods for logging the errors so I am not getting any needful info even after debugging its methods

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ with Maven, t can download the matching source code automatically, and it allows you debugging through it. You shouldn't debug the code of the exception helper, but you can place a breakpoint in it to find the caller and the endless recursion.